# How to send image(png) via slackbot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack, slack-api

The documentation gives us a way to post an image via slackbot using the image url. I don't actually have the image url. I receive the image as a "base64 encoded PNG (string)" in my nodejs code . How can I post this via a slack bot?

Answer (score 0):

Try posting the image as a file instead of message.

https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload

Comment: I used this api. It did not work . I got `'no file data'` error.Here's the code:
https://pastebin.com/puFZb17Y
 @suyash-gaur

Comment: Seems like you need to convert base64 code back to an image file in your working directory and then use file path to upload the image. Later you can delete the local copy of the image. You'll need `file` argument instead of `content`